# Why do we subtract the variance?

Tags: statistics

This is not a question for doing my homework. This is a question to understand the deeper meaning of the answer. So in part b), it subtracts the variance. Why do we subtract variance and what does it mean to subtract variance? I understood variance as the distance the numbers are spread apart, so what does subtracting that mean?

Question:

> Suppose that 30% of all students who
>   have to buy a text for a particular
>   course want a new copy (the
>   successes!), whereas the other 70%
>   want a used copy. Consider randomly
>   selecting 25 purchasers. a. What are
>   the mean value and standard deviation
>   of the number who want a new copy of
>   the book? b. What is the probability
>   that the number who want new copies is
>   more than two standard deviations away
>   from the mean value?

Answer:

> X ~ Bin(25,.3)
>
> a. E(X) = np = 7.5;
>   Var(X) = npq = 5.25 → SD(X) = 2.29
>
> b.    P(|X – 5.25| > 2(2.29)) = P(X <
>   0.67 or X > 9.83) = P(X = 0) + P(X > 9.83) = b(0;25,.3) + 1 – P(X ≤ 9) = b(0;25,.3) + 1 – B(9;25,.3) = .000 + 1
>   – .811 = .189

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a mistake. They should have subtracted the mean.

The correct answer is 
$$P(|X – 7.5| > 2(2.29)) = P(X < 2.92\mbox{ or }X > 12.08)=.02643 .$$